# Neovim how to exit insert mode without any delay

Tags: neovim

I've just started a new neovim configuration based on [kickstart.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim).

When I'm working I often want to quickly switch out of insert mode to do something in normal mode in one fluid motion.  However, when I press the Escape key there is about a half-second delay where I'm still in insert mode.

It kind of feels like neovim is waiting to see if I have other keystrokes to chain after that initial Escape.  Is there a way to remove this delay and have Escape instantly register, or some other way to instantly switch from Insert to Normal mode?

Comment: Check key bindings with `:imap <esc>?`. Also, see if the delay persists with a clean environment (`nvim --clean`)

Answer (score 1):

The time span of switching out depends on a variable named `ttimeoutlen` and the Wait time for a mapped sequence to complete depends on `timeoutlen`. Both are global variables, To decrease the time of switching out from insert mode you can add these lines in your nvim config file,

lua

```
vim.opt.ttimeoutlen = 50 --in milliseconds
```

vim

```
:set ttimeoutlen=50 " in milliseconds
```

Consider seeing `:h ttimeoutlen` & `:h timeoutlen`

Additionally, if you're using tmux then you can add this line in your `.tmux.conf`

```bash
set -g escape-time 0
```